# Vector regression with Keras

Tags: keras

Suppose, for example, a regression problem with five scalars as output, where each output has approximately the same range. In Keras, we can model this using a 5-output dense layer without activation function (vector regression):

```
output_layer = layers.Dense(5, activation=None)(previous_layer)
model = models.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
```

Is the total loss (metric) simply the sum of the individual losses (metrics)? Is this equivalent to the following multi-output model, where the outputs have the same implicit loss weights? In my experiments, I haven't observed any significant differences but want to make sure that I didn't miss anything fundamental.

```
output_layer_list = []
for _ in range(5):
    output_layer_list.append(layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(previous_layer))
model = models.Model(input_layer, output_layer_list)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
```

Is there an easy way to attach weights to the outputs in the first solution similar to specifying `loss_weights` in case of multi-output models?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are equivalent. To replicate the `loss_weights` functionality with your first model, you can define your own custom loss function. Something along these lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf
weights = K.variable(value=np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6]]))

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.matmul(K.square(y_true - y_pred), tf.transpose(weights))
```

and pass this function to the `loss` argument upon compiling:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=custom_loss, metrics=['mse'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Those models are the *same*. To answer your questions let's look at the [mse loss](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e77a4cf3f85b45ad4275dfd661073ace1cc06e5a/keras/losses.py#L14):

```
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

1. *Is the total loss (metric) simply the sum of the individual losses (metrics)?* **Yes**, because the mse loss applies the `K.mean` function so you can argue it is the sum of all the elements in the output vector.
2. *Is this equivalent to the following multi-output model, where the outputs have the same implicit loss weights?* **Yes**, because subtraction and squaring are done **element wise** in vector form, so scalar outputs will produce the same as a single vector output. And a multi-output model loss is the sum of losses of individual outputs.